# How to set image in imageview in adapter and getting uri in another activity?

Tags: android

(This is my adapter)(I want to display image in the imageview ivReceiverSign The image url is saved in signature class displayed below.)

```
DbAdapter

package com.example.dhruvitpatel.deviceregistration.adapter;
public class DbAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DbAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    List<RegisterDevice> registerDevice;
    Context mCtx;
    String rowAdded;

    public DbAdapter(List<RegisterDevice> registerDevice, Context mCtx) {
        this.registerDevice = registerDevice;
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        return new DbAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DbAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final RegisterDevice registerdetails = registerDevice.get(position);
        holder.registerDate.setText("Register Date: " + registerdetails.getOutDate() + registerdetails.getOutTime());
        holder.EmpName.setText("Name: " + registerdetails.getEmpName());
        holder.Cable.setText("Cable: " + registerdetails.getCableName());
        holder.Device.setText("Device: " + registerdetails.getDevName());
        holder.ivUserSign.setImageURI(Uri.parse(registerdetails.getUserSign()));

        holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mCtx);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure, You want to submit Device?");

                    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
                            final Dialog submitDialog = new Dialog(mCtx);
                            submitDialog.setContentView(R.layout.submitdevicedialog);
                            submitDialog.show();

                            TextView tvSubmittedTo = (TextView) submitDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvSubmittedTo);
                            final EditText etReceivedBy = (EditText) submitDialog.findViewById(R.id.etReceivedBy);
                            Button btnSubmitDevice = (Button) submitDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSubmitDevice);
                            Button btnCancelSubmit = (Button) submitDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelSubmit);

                            btnSubmitDevice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    String receiver = etReceivedBy.getText().toString();
                                    if (receiver.isEmpty()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Enter receiver Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else {
                                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                        SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd / MM / yyyy ");
                                        String submitDate = mdformat.format(cal.getTime());
                                        DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
                                        String submitTime = date.format(cal);
                                        long id = registerdetails.getPid();

                                        DataSource.updateSubmittedDevice(submitDate, submitTime, receiver, id);




                                        Intent in = new Intent(mCtx, Signature.class);
                                        in.putExtra("Id", String.valueOf(id));
                                        Log.d("ID:", String.valueOf(id));
                                        mCtx.startActivity(in);

                                        String recSign = registerdetails.getReceiverSign();
                                        registerdetails.setSubmitDate(submitDate);
                                        registerdetails.setSubmitTime(submitTime);
                                        registerdetails.setReciever(receiver);
                                        registerdetails.setDeviceSubmitted(true);
                                        registerdetails.setReceiverSign(recSign);
                                        registerDevice.remove(position);
                                        registerDevice.add(position, registerdetails);
                                        notifyItemChanged(position);

                                        holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                        if (registerdetails.getDeviceSubmitted().equals(Boolean.TRUE)) {
                                            String temp = registerdetails.getDevName();
                                            String temp1 = registerdetails.getCableName();

                                            DataSource.updateDataonLoad(temp, temp1);
                                        }

                                    }

                                }
                            });
                            btnCancelSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    submitDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

                    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }
        });


        if (registerdetails.getDeviceSubmitted().equals(Boolean.TRUE)) {
//            if(!registerdetails.getReceiverSign().isEmpty()){
//                holder.ivReceiverSign.setImageURI(Uri.parse(registerdetails.getReceiverSign()));
//            }
            holder.card_view.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

            holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.tvSubmit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.tvReceiver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.submitDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.tvReceiver.setText(registerdetails.getReciever());
            holder.submitDate.setText("Submit Date: " + registerdetails.getSubmitDate() + registerdetails.getSubmitTime());


        } else {
            holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return registerDevice.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.registerDate)
        TextView registerDate;
        @BindView(R.id.EmpName)
        TextView EmpName;
        @BindView(R.id.Device)
        TextView Device;
        @BindView(R.id.Cable)
        TextView Cable;
        @BindView(R.id.checkbox)
        CheckBox checkbox;
        @BindView(R.id.tvReceiver)
        TextView tvReceiver;
        @BindView(R.id.tvSubmit)
        TextView tvSubmit;
        @BindView(R.id.submitDate)
        TextView submitDate;
        @BindView(R.id.card_view)
        CardView card_view;
        @BindView(R.id.ivUserSign)
        ImageView ivUserSign;
        @BindView(R.id.ivReceiverSign)
        ImageView ivReceiverSign;


        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }
}

Register class
(Here I register devices which are loaded in spinner from database.After selecting items i will click on register button and all details will be notified to adapter )  
Register Page

package com.example.dhruvitpatel.deviceregistration.activity;
    public class TakeDevice extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
        @BindView(R.id.spnName)
        Spinner spnName;
        @BindView(R.id.spnDevice)
        Spinner spnDevice;
        @BindView(R.id.spnCable)
        Spinner spnCable;
        @BindView(R.id.btnRegister)
        Button btnRegister;
        @BindView(R.id.col)
        CoordinatorLayout col;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_device);
            ButterKnife.bind(this);

            initView();
            setListener();
            loadempData();
            loaddevdata();
            loadcabledata();
        }

        private void initView() {
            spnName.requestFocus();
        }

        private void setListener() {
            btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        private void loadempData() {

            final List<EmployeeDetails> values = DataSource.getempData();
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, values);
            adapter.add("Select your name");
            spnName.setAdapter(adapter);
            spnName.setSelection(adapter.getCount()-1);
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {

                case R.id.btnRegister:
                    empName = spnName.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    devName = spnDevice.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    Cable = spnCable.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    if (empName.isEmpty() && devName.isEmpty() && Cable.isEmpty()) {
                        Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(col, "Select details", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snack.show();
                    }

                    if (Cable.equals("Select cable")){
                        Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(col, "Select cable", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snack.show();
                    }
                    else if(empName.equals("Select your name")){
                        Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(col, "Select name", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snack.show();
                    }
                    else if (devName.equals("Select device")){
                        Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(col, "Select device", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snack.show();
                    }

                    else if (empName.isEmpty()) {
                        Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(col, "Select name", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snack.show();
                    } else if (devName.isEmpty() && Cable.isEmpty()) {
                        Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(col, "Select device or cable", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snack.show();
                    } else {
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd / MM / yyyy ");
                        String strDate = mdformat.format(cal.getTime());
                        DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
                        String strTime = date.format(cal);

                        deviceTaken = new RegisterDevice();
                        deviceTaken.setOutDate(strDate);
                        deviceTaken.setOutTime(strTime);
                        deviceTaken.setEmpName(empName);
                        deviceTaken.setDevName(devName);
                        deviceTaken.setCableName(Cable);
                        DataSource.insertDetails(deviceTaken);

                        long regDevList = deviceTaken.getPid();
                        DataSource.updateBoolean(deviceIdDisp, cableIdDisp);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Signature.class);
                        intent.putExtra("RowId", String.valueOf(regDevList));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    break;
            }


    (I get my image url in this class.i use this to get signature and i have four buttons in it)
            Signature class



    package com.example.dhruvitpatel.deviceregistration.activity;
        public class Signature extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

            @BindView(R.id.btnSave)
            Button btnSave;
            @BindView(R.id.signLayout)
            LinearLayout signLayout;
            @BindView(R.id.btnRedo)
            Button btnRedo;
            @BindView(R.id.btnUndo)
            Button btnUndo;
            @BindView(R.id.btnClear)
            Button btnClear;
            @BindView(R.id.cordlayout)
            CoordinatorLayout cordlayout;

            private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 111;
            public static String tempDir;
            private String uniqueId;
            File mypath;
            public String current = null;
            View mView;
            signature mSignature;
            Uri signImage;
            private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
            private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
            private Path mPath;
            long id;
            public boolean cc = false;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_signature);
                ButterKnife.bind(this);
                initView();
                setListener();
            }

            private void initView() {
                btnSave.setEnabled(false);
                tempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir) + "/";
                ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
                File directory = cw.getDir(getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


                uniqueId = getTodayDate() + "_" + getCurrentTime() + "_" + Math.random();
                current = uniqueId + ".jpeg";
                mypath = new File(directory, current);
                Log.d("path:", String.valueOf(mypath));

                mSignature = new signature(this, null);
                mSignature.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                signLayout.addView(mSignature, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                mView = signLayout;

                btnRedo.setEnabled(false);

            }

            private String getTodayDate() {

                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int todaysDate = (c.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 10000) +
                        ((c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) * 100) +
                        (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                Log.w("DATE:", String.valueOf(todaysDate));
                return (String.valueOf(todaysDate));
            }

            private String getCurrentTime() {

                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int currentTime = (c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 10000) +
                        (c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 100) +
                        (c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                Log.w("TIME:", String.valueOf(currentTime));
                return (String.valueOf(currentTime));
            }

            private void setListener() {
                btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
                btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);
                btnUndo.setOnClickListener(this);
                btnRedo.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.btnSave:
                        // Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Saved");
                        if (!CommonUtils.checkPermission(Signature.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                            CommonUtils.requestPermission(Signature.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, GALLERY_REQUEST);
                        } else {
                            mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                            mSignature.save(mView);
                        }

                    case R.id.btnClear:
                        mSignature.clear();

                        // mPath=new Path();

        //                mSignature.invalidate();
                        btnSave.setEnabled(false);
                        break;

                    case R.id.btnUndo:
                        if (paths.size() > 0) {
                            undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
                            mSignature.invalidate();
                            btnRedo.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                        break;


                    case R.id.btnRedo:
                        if (undonePaths.size() > 0) {
                            paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size() - 1));
                            btnRedo.setEnabled(true);
                            mSignature.invalidate();
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                    case GALLERY_REQUEST:
                        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                            mSignature.save(mView);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            public class signature extends View {
                private Bitmap mBitmap;
                private Canvas mCanvas;

                Context context;
                private Paint mPaint;
                private float mX, mY;
                private static final float TOLERANCE = 5;


                public signature(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
                    super(c, attrs);
                    context = c;
                    // we set a new Path
                    mPath = new Path();
                    // and we set a new Paint with the desired attributes
                    mPaint = new Paint();
                    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                    mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
                    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(15f);

                }

                public void save(View v) {

                    if (mBitmap == null) {
                        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(signLayout.getWidth(), signLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                    }
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
                    if (paths.isEmpty() && undonePaths.isEmpty()) {
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(cordlayout, "Enter your signature", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snackbar.show();
                    } else {
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
                            v.draw(canvas);
                            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, mFileOutStream);
                            mFileOutStream.flush();
                            mFileOutStream.close();
                            String url = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "title:" + current, null);
                            Log.v("log_tag", "url: " + url);

                            String rowId = getIntent().getStringExtra("RowId");
                            if (rowId != null) {
                                id = Long.parseLong(rowId);
                                Log.d("id:", String.valueOf(id));
                                signImage = Uri.fromFile(mypath);
                                Log.d("uri:", String.valueOf(signImage));
                                DataSource.updateSign(signImage, id);
                            }
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Signature.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("RowId", String.valueOf(id));
                            setResult(1, intent);
                            startActivity(intent);


                            Intent in = getIntent();
                            String submitId = in.getStringExtra("Id");
                            if (submitId != null) {
                                long subId = Long.parseLong(submitId);
                                Uri recsignImage = Uri.fromFile(mypath);
                                DataSource.updateReceiversign(recsignImage, subId);
                            }

                            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Signature.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent1.putExtra("ID", String.valueOf(submitId));
                            setResult(2, intent1);
                            startActivity(intent1);
                            //In case you want to delete the file
                            //boolean deleted = mypath.delete();
                            //Log.v("log_tag","deleted: " + mypath.toString() + deleted);
                            //If you want to convert the image to string use base64 converter

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }

                // override onSizeChanged
                @Override
                protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {

                    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
                    // your Canvas will draw onto the defined Bitmap
                    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
                }

                // override onDraw
                @Override
                protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                    if (cc) {
                        Paint clearPaint = new Paint();
                        clearPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 0, 0, clearPaint);
                        cc = false;
                    }
        //            // draw the mPath with the mPaint on the canvas when onDraw
        //            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
                    else {
                        for (Path p : paths) {
                            canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
                        }
                        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
                    }
                }

                // when ACTION_DOWN start touch according to the x,y values
                private void startTouch(float x, float y) {
                    undonePaths.clear();
                    mPath.reset();
                    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
                    mX = x;
                    mY = y;

                }

                // when ACTION_MOVE move touch according to the x,y values
                private void moveTouch(float x, float y) {
                    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
                    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);

                    if (dx >= TOLERANCE || dy >= TOLERANCE) {
                        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                        mX = x;
                        mY = y;
                    }
                }

                // when ACTION_UP stop touch
                private void upTouch() {
                    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
                    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
                    paths.add(mPath);
                    mPath = new Path();
                }

                //override the onTouchEvent
                @Override
                public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

                    float x = event.getX();
                    float y = event.getY();

                    switch (event.getAction()) {

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            btnSave.setEnabled(true);
                            startTouch(x, y);
                            invalidate();
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            btnSave.setEnabled(true);
                            moveTouch(x, y);
                            invalidate();
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            btnSave.setEnabled(true);
                            upTouch();
                            invalidate();
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                public void clear() {
                    paths.clear();
                    undonePaths.clear();
                    cc = true;
                    invalidate();
                }
            }


            }
        }
```

Wat to do if i want to set image in imageview of my adapter wid id ivReceiverSign?

Answer (score 0):

Create interface

```
 public interface ImageUrl{
        void getImageUrl(String imageUrl)
    }
```

implement this interface in adapter and send the url through another class using `imageUrl.getImageUrl(imageUrl).`

or Use EventBus library.

Reference to Eventbus : [Green robot Event bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)